# Responsive Design mal, HTML

Tags: html, css

me encuentro desarrollando como proyecto escolar una página de la escuela, así que decidí que también se pudiera ver en telefonos, pero al momento de que la abría alli, me salía mal, y decidí hacer la página Responsive Design, pero me ocurre algo tanto con móviles, pc , tablets.

Esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces,como hago para quitar ese espacio blanco?

Ya usé:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximun-scale=1.0, minimun-scale=1.0">


  @media screen and (max-width:400px){
    .all{
      widht:100%;

    }
  }
```

Y también ya usé lo de poner 100% o 90% pero nada.

Comment: Como dice @BetaM, agrega el html completo y el css, lo mas probable es que se este desbordando algun margin, padding, imagen, etc..

Comment: Viendo la URL de tu página, tienes un div con `id #efecto` que tiene un `width: 1355px;` por eso se desborda del viewport, asígnale por ejemplo un `width: 100%;`

Comment: si , al parecer fue lo de #efecto